# Subdifferential of a convex function

Tags: convex-analysis, differential-topology, convex-optimization, subgradient

How would I find a convex function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\partial f(0) = [0,1]$

A subdifferential is just the collection of vectors $w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that

$f(y) \geq f(x_0) + \langle w,y-x_0\rangle$, $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and
$\partial f(x_0) \neq \emptyset$.

I am unsure how to extend this definition to my question, and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Hint: What is the subdifferential of $|x|$ at $0$?

Comment: This would be [-1,1] ?

Comment: Yes, try to use $|x|$ to construct the function you want.

Comment: Would 
$$
f(x)= 
\begin{cases}
    x^2,& \text{if } x\leq 0\\
    x,              & x > 0
\end{cases}$$ work?

Comment: I think so. Might be $f(x) = 0$ for $x\leq 0$ would be more obvious?

Comment: haha, definitely. I've familiarised myself with this now, not quite as confusing anymore, thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

I think that

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
0,&\text{ if } x \leq 0
\\
x,&\text{ if } x > 0
\end{cases}
$$

is a good example.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

The key trick would be to introduce a discontinuity in the derivative of the function $f$ at $x=0$.

Let $f$ be of the form

$$ 
f(x) = \begin{cases}
g(x),&\text{ if } x \leq 0
\\
h(x),&\text{ if } x > 0
\end{cases}
$$
such that both $g$ and $h$ are differentiable, $g(0) = h(0)$, $g'(0) = 0$, $h'(0) = 1$, any choice of smooth $g$ and $h$ would fit the bill.

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
0,&\text{ if } x \leq 0
\\
x,&\text{ if } x > 0
\end{cases}
$$
suggested by @giulio-binosi fits the bill.

So does a more complicated
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{3}x^3,&\text{ if } x \leq 0
\\
\frac{1}{2}x^2 + x,&\text{ if } x > 0
\end{cases}
$$